# Node Js, Separating DB models and Proxy

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am creating an TODO application (REST API). I am using Node JS, express and sequelize. I have defined my models (db entities) and controllers. now I don't want all the fields in my db to be exposed to the client application. like we normally do in any LOB application, So I need to create an Proxy Object for each model that i have. I searched on net for how to create reusable proxy classes in node js way over the net. but i couldn't find any. I also like to use a mapper like we do in java for copying properties with same name from model to proxy and reverse. can you guys share an example on how to do this?

Comment: Can't you select only the fields you want to expose?

Comment: actually in the entity there will be many fields, i might need that for processing the request, but the response, only needed values are to be returned, not the entire db entity.

Comment: Probably is not what you want, but in that case when you create the response you can send only the fields you want.

Comment: Eg: _.pick(entity, 'fieldA', 'fieldB') (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#pick)